# Updated the .htaccess and website doesn't load now.. what shall i put in to restore it?

Tags: .htaccess

thanks a million! my website is not loading now .please. please.please!

```
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Well, now that i solved the loading page problem. I'll explain myself better...

all i wanted to do is those redirections:

http://www.domain.com/ -> http://domain.com/

http://domain.com -> http://domain.com/

http://domain.com/article/55/any-name-here-wont-even-check -> http://domain.com/page.php?id=55

Mi go was (the last redirect it's an old->new domain name. It's also done through cPanel):

```
    RewriteEngine On

#Options +FollowSymLinks



RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^article/(.+)/(.+) page.php?id=$1


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldname.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^oldname.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Is correct? if so, any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Try to access your error log, it should tell you what's wrong. You could also provide the contents of your .htaccess file here.

Comment: Have you tried removing the last thing you updated? Post your code so we can help you!

Comment: Post your code, please. Not the `500` error message.

Comment: ended up Renaming folder, creating folder with previous name, and moving files...

Comment: by the way, my last update fas de .htaccess file. trying to build url fiendly..

Comment: First step would be to remove it, which should restore access to your site. Next, figure out what went wrong, starting with looking at the permissions on that file, after that, probably a syntax error in the file.

Comment: guys thanks for writing and excuse my poor previous explanation, i was nervious. I edited. I hope you have a minuto to check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and see if it works for you.

```
RewriteEngine on
RwritteBase /
RewriteRule ^article/([^/\.]+)(/.*)?$ page.php?id=$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldname\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^oldname\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://newname.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: it doesn't give me error. but i'm not sure wha'ts loading... :S styles are weird. Regular links work fine though... any idea?

Comment: thanks, but i ment the first redirection, to page.php?id=... if y type a friendly domain/article/5/some-name it goes to my index and with no CSS styling